# How can i make a prefab instantiate another prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2010

So basically, lets say i have a cannon, i wanted to make it shoot a cannonball(prefabs) and leave an explosion(prefab) at the place it collided.

example code for projectile:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class projectiles : MonoBehaviour
{
    

public int life;
    cannonball cannonball

    private void Awake()
    {

        Destroy(gameObject, life);
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        GameObject endeffect = Instantiate(explosion, body.position, body.rotation, spells);
        endeffectrb.transform.localscale*= cannonball.size;

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
'''

example code for explosion:
'''
using UnityEngine;

public class cannonball: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ball;
    public Transform player;
    public Transform cam;

    public KeyCode shootkey = KeyCode.Mouse0;

    public float speed = 10;
    public float size= 10f;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(shootkey))
        {
            shoot();

        }
    }
    public void shoot()
    {
        player.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(1 * size / 10, 1 * size / 10, 1 * size / 10);
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(ball, player.position, cam.rotation);
        projectile.transform.localScale *= size / 10;
        Rigidbody ballrb = projectile.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        ballrb.useGravity = false;
        ballrb.AddForce(cam.rotation * Vector3.fwd * speed, ForceMode.Force);

    }
}
```

But however after i instantiate the cannonballs from the cannon, I cant get it to instantiate an explosion as well as being unable to access the explosion gameobject and change its properties. I spent a few hours trying to solve this but all the resources i found did not mention anything about instantiating from a prefab so pls help.

[this for projectile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MYSy.png)

[this for cannon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iPMi.png)

this is whats going on so far

Comment: Leaving out some mistakes and making some assumptions (like explosion being defined), the code looks fine to me. Are you sure explosion is set correctly? Do you get any error, like NullReferenceException? Also make sure the surface which the ball collides with has a Rigidbody, or else the OnCollisionEnter won´t fire.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if **life** > 0
2. check if **Awake** occurs

```cs
private void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log("Awake");
 }
```

3. check if **OnCollisionEnter** occurs

```cs
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
 {
      Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter");
 }
```

4. Check if the **explosion** and **cannonball** are initialized - it's not obvious where they came from!
5. Check out **[Console](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Console.html)** for errors

That's enough to find the problem and fix it, or ask a good question.

Comment: Ive checked the inspector for all the gameobject the scripts are attached to and all of them were properly connected. Like for the cannon is set to initialize a cannonball(prefab) and the prefab cannonball is set to instantiate the prefab explosion.

Also the awake and oncollisionenter both works and there are no errors in code

Comment: @AidenChan, your code is not real. "projectiles" does not have the "explosion" variable. Although the question is not correct, the answer is - yes, it can. Why doesn't it work? You need to look for it yourself.